# Execute jQuery from ajax loaded page

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to use [jQuery UI Tabs with Ajax](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#ajax) and load the content from other pages.

The pages I try to load contain other jQuery functions and the problem is that only jQuery for the first tab is executed.
How can I fire the code in the other tabs only when I activate the tab?

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: check you tab, if it is activated, do your code, please create your jsfiddle for more help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to be using the "activate" event of jQuery UI Tabs. For documentation: http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-activate

```
$(function() {
    $( "#categoryTabs" ).tabs({
        activate: function(event, ui) {
            var current_tab = ui.newTab;

            // make sure you have added "data-tab-value" to tab html eg <div class="tab" data-tab-value="0" ..
            var tab_value = $(current_tab).attr('data-tab-value');

            switch (tab_value) {
                case 0:
                    // first tab actions go here
                    break;
                case 1:
                    // second tab actions go here
                    break;
                case 2:
                    // third tab actions go here
                    break;
            }
        },
    }).addClass( "ui-tabs-vertical ui-helper-clearfix" );
    $( "#categoryTabs li" ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-left" );
});
```